# what is the android APIs supported by opencv library?

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection, eye-tracking

I am trying to use opencv(2.4.9) with android studio(2.3.3) to develop an eye tracking application used mainly on tablet ...
my question is : what is the suitable API verstion of the android device that can i use? and is the model of the device has an effect ??

by the way, i tried to open the camera with opencv using API(21,22,25)on the android emulator but it does not work ... and with a real phone(API 25) also not working ... and using the genemotion emulator(API 22 & 21) and also it does not work

Answer (score 1):

As official documentation says:

> The minimal platform supported by OpenCV Java API is Android 2.2 (API
>   8)

armeabi, armv7a-neon, arm7a-neon-android8, mips and x86 stand for platform targets:

- armeabi is for ARM v5 and ARM v6 architectures with Android API 8+,
- armv7a-neon is for NEON-optimized ARM v7 with Android API 9+,
- arm7a-neon-android8 is for NEON-optimized ARM v7 with Android API 8,
- mips is for MIPS architecture with Android API 9+,   x86 is for Intel
- x86 CPUs with Android API 9+.

[More info](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)